# How to programmatically define a global function within a function or method?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

For example,

```
def makeFunction name
    ... #define a function with the name supplied
end

makeFunction 'functionMade'
functionMade
```

I know it's possible to make a global variable `$functionMade` through `lambda` or `proc`, but is it possible to make it really a function without the `$` prefix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think via `class_eval` on `Kernel`:

```
Kernel.class_eval <<-RUBY
  def abc
    puts 'abc'
  end
RUBY
```

but i wouldn't recommend that. what do you need it for, or are you just curious?

Comment: Cool! I want to generate a set of functions as specified in an externally loaded JSON. :)

Comment: :D indeed! Remember eval is Evil

Comment: @albert: Have you looked at whether Struct or OpenStruct would suit your needs?

Comment: that's dangerous.. you could accidentally monkey-patch / override something that's built-in to Ruby.. Danger Will Robinson!

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: I am making an assembly code generator. There are hundreds of instructions from the datasheet. I just paste the spec such as `'ADC{S}<c><q> {<Rd>,} <Rn>, #<const>'`, and parse it to make functions, so that the Ruby code look like the assembly code.

`adc R1, R2, 100`

This produce the actual assembly code,

`adc R1, R2, #100`

I have done this in javascript, but Ruby seems to be much more close for the code generation purpose.